# I can't stop my media player in android?

Tags: android, media-player

Am using mediaplayer to play tick sound in timer.But it continues to play after timer is over,Even after i called stop for media player. I played sound as seen below in ontick() in timer. In onfinish() called mp.Stop(),But it not working.

```
              mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        });
        mp.setLooping(false);
        // mp.setVolume(0.1, 0.1);
        mp.start();
}
```

**coding for my timer .**

```
final class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timer.cancel();

        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.release();
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                }

            }
        };
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
        i++;
        submitAnswer();
        final GameEngine ge = GameEngine.getInstance();

        timeer.setText("Timer Completed.");

        if (ge.getCurrentUnAllocatedAmount() > 0 && i <= 8) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,
                            ScoreActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("level", i);
                    ge.setCurrentLevel(i);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 2200);
        } else if (ge.getCurrentUnAllocatedAmount() <= 0 || i > 8) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,
                    ScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("level", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        remTime = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        timeer.setText("Time:" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "");
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.beep7);
        if (remTime > 0) {
            mp.start();
            mp.release();
        }
        if (remTime < 10) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (timeer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        timeer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        timeer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    timeer.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mp.stop() on onCompletion of player

Comment: i tried calling mp.pause() too. it not working.

Comment: try to write mp.stop() and mp.reset() on onCompletion of player

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
mp.stop();
    });
```

Comment: make me assure, it happens every time or it happens too when you stay on the same intent in which you called media Player ??

Comment: After the timer end it moves to another activity. but still continues to play sound.

Comment: if you have to stop player against your timer so why u r calling onCompletion ??
just use mp.stop() when timer ends.

Comment: that is answer given by user..but nothing works..even mp.stop()

Comment: please debug your code and check when u stop() mp object is not a new instance or null

Comment: what is the return of mp.getDuration() just before you stop media player (mp.stop() ) ??

Comment: i think problem in my timer. i think timer starts run again after onfinish().i ill check and update

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if(mp.isPlaying())
                        {
                             mp.stop();
                             mp.reset();
                        }

                }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling the `release()` method on the `onCompletionListener()` itself.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.release();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

       if (mp.isPlaying()) {
           mp.stop();
            }

            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }


    });
```

Comment: The last line `mp = null` is useless, since it only affects the variable `mp` inside the method `onCompletion`. The reference count for it was going to decrease anyway at the end of `onCompletion`.

Answer (score -1):

Check condition when timer is stop.

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    mPlayer.stop();
}
```

Comment: take a look at other users answer before posting something!!